# Stream with lambda expression over DTOs

Tags: lambda, java-8, parallel-processing, java-stream

I have array of 'Student' class. Student class has two fields:

```
private final String firstName; 
private final boolean isCurrent;
```

'checkIsCurrent' api present in 'Student' class shall give false value, if student is inactive.

Following is my DTO class.

```
/**
* A class representing a single student in a single class.
*/
public final class Student2 {
/**
 * First name of the student.
 */
private final String firstName;
/**
 * Whether the student is currently enrolled, or has already completed the
 * course.
 */
private final boolean isCurrent;

/**
 * Constructor.
 * @param setFirstName Student first name
 * @param setIsCurrent Student currently enrolled?
 */
public Student2(final String setFirstName,final boolean setIsCurrent) {
    this.firstName = setFirstName;
    this.isCurrent = setIsCurrent;
}

/**
 * Get the first name of this student.
 * @return The student's first name.
 */
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}


/**
 * Check if this student is active, or has taken the course in the past.
 * @return true if the student is currently enrolled, false otherwise
 */
public boolean checkIsCurrent() {
    return isCurrent;
}
}
```

Now I want to know most common first name of inactive students?

I want to do this, with parallel stream ?

```
 public String mostCommonFirstNameOfInactiveStudentsParallelStream(final Student[] studentArray) {
       try{
            return Stream.of(studentArray)
                     .parallel()
                     .filter(s->!s.checkIsCurrent())
                     .map(s->s.getFirstName())                   
          }
          catch(Exception e){
             throw e;
          }
 }
```

What will be parallel stream code for this?

Comment: Focus on correctness first, then maybe think about whether parallelism is a sensible optimization.

Answer (score 4):

You should decide whether your class is `Student` or `Student2`. Further, don’t insert arbitrary `try … catch` blocks.

One way of achieving the goal would be

```
public String mostCommonFirstNameOfInactiveStudentsParallelStream(Student2[] studentArray){
    return Arrays.stream(studentArray)
             .parallel()
             .filter(s->!s.checkIsCurrent())
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Student2::getFirstName, s -> 1, Integer::sum))
             .entrySet().stream()
             .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
             .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
             .orElse(null);
}
```

An alternative is

```
public String mostCommonFirstNameOfInactiveStudentsParallelStream(Student2[] studentArray){
    return Arrays.stream(studentArray)
             .parallel()
             .filter(s->!s.checkIsCurrent())
             .collect(Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(Student2::getFirstName,
                                                      Collectors.summingInt(s -> 1)))
             .entrySet().stream()
             .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
             .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
             .orElse(null);
}
```

which one is faster, depends on several circumstances. You may also replace `toMap` by `toConcurrentMap` or `groupingByConcurrent` by `groupingBy`, ending up at four alternatives to test.

But most likely, a sequential stream will be faster than a parallel stream anyway, as it is rather unlikely that you have so many objects, that parallel processing will pay off.

Comment: How about this answer? `Arrays.stream(studentArray)
                .parallel()
                .filter(s -> !s.checkIsCurrent())
                .map(s -> s.getFirstName())
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(
                                Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()
                        ))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .max((entry1, entry2) -> entry1.getValue() > entry2.getValue() ? 1 : -1).get().getKey();`

Comment: @HadiJeddizahed: there is no sense in inserting `.collect(Collectors.toList()) .stream()` into the pipeline, it has no semantic effect, but wastes resource. Further, `(entry1, entry2) -> entry1.getValue() > entry2.getValue() ? 1 : -1` is an invalid comparator, as it does not return `0` for equal values, even if it might happen to work with `max` in this context. And there is no reason to write such a comparator manually, when there is a correct `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()` anyway. And `Optional.get()` may fail when there were no matching elements…

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `groupingBy` collector:

```
   return Stream.of(studentArray)
                .parallel()
                .filter(s -> !s.checkIsCurrent()) 
                .map(Student::getFirstName())   
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .min(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().reversed())
                .map(Entry::getKey).orElse(null);
```

Another option would be using [Collections.frequency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency-java.util.Collection-java.lang.Object-) although that requires you override `equals`/`hashcode`.

Comment: Yeah, `sorted(…) .findFirst()` is quiet an inefficient alternative to say “`min`”, unless the stream does recognize and replace this (which afaik does not happen in the current implementation).

Comment: Your first comment is taken into consideration. 9th edit :( . I think ideone does work on smartphones, but I rarely use it. nevertheless very much appreciated for the useful comments again :) .

Comment: Note that type inference works better for nested invocations than for chained, so instead of `Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().reversed()`, you can use `Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())` without explicit types (then you can use `import static` for the methods). Mut when using `max` instead of `min`, you don’t need to reverse the comparator…